# How to bind a custom value to the Text property of a TextBlock inside of a ListBox DataTemplate?

Tags: wpf, listbox, datatemplate, wcf-binding

I would like my **ListBox** to number each **ListItem** using its index + 1.

How would I do that to the **Text** property of a **TextBlock** in a **DataTemplate** of the **ListBox**?

Answer (score 1):

If each `ListBoxItem` uses `SelectedIndex + 1`, they will all display the same value since `SelectedIndex` is a scalar. Moreover, this number will change as the user selects different `ListBoxItems`. I suspect you actually want to display each item's index within the `ListBox` + 1.

To achieve this, you're probably best off using the `ListBox`'s [ItemsContainerGenerator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemcontainergenerator.aspx) to get the index of the item within the container (see the [IndexFromContainer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemcontainergenerator.indexfromcontainer.aspx) method). You could look at exposing this from your data class, or perhaps look into an attached readonly property that retrieves this value for you.

Answer (score 0):

I had [the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/660528/how-to-display-row-numbers-in-a-listview). So far I'm just using my data model to provide the numbers...