# WPF: The resource "IndexConverter" could not be resolved

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, data-binding, resources

I'm trying to bind the indices of a ListView to a column in the list for display purposes.

Eventually, I'd also like to be able to remove an entry using a "delete" button inside the row's DataTemplate, but getting the binding working is step one.

This (or some variation) seems to be one of the most popular answers:
[How to display row numbers in a ListView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/660528/how-to-display-row-numbers-in-a-listview)

Here's what I have so far:
XAML:

```
<GridViewColumn Header="Index" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListViewItem}}, Converter={StaticResource IndexConverter}}">
</GridViewColumn>
```

C#:

```
public class IndexConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type TargetType, object parameter)
    {
        ListViewItem item = (ListViewItem)value;
        ListView listView = ItemsControl.ItemsControlFromItemContainer(item) as ListView;
        int index = listView.ItemContainerGenerator.IndexFromContainer(item);
        return index.ToString();
    }
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

I put that function in the CS file for my application view.

It's telling me it can't resolve the resource for IndexConverter.  I feel like this is probably a quick fix, and I've either put the function in the wrong spot or there's some line of code I'm missing to add the resource.  However, the solution in the link doesn't clear this up.

UPDATE:

Based on sa_ddam213's suggestions, I've edited my App.xaml file to include this:

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApplication1.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:myConverters="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1.Views"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Themes/DarkTheme.xaml" />
        <myConverters:IndexConverter x:Key="IndexConverter" />
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

I'm now getting an error saying that the resource can only be set once.  Commenting out the DarkTheme eliminates that error, but it then says that IndexConverter does not exist in the WpfApplication1.Views namespace, which is definitely where I put it.

Comment: Can you show the xaml where you added the converter to your resources

Comment: @sa_ddam213: This is not something I did.  That's basically what I'm asking about - how to add it and where it goes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up accomplishing this in a recent project.  I had a ListView in which I wanted the user to be able to re-order the items (move the entries up and down with arrow keys and/or buttons).

I added a new member to the class of the collection, called SortOrder, which I assigned a unique value to for each new item that was added.  I then wrote a function to sort the collection items based on the SortOrder, along with functions to move an item up or down one space.

The SortOrder property can then by bound to and displayed in a column, since it's a member of the class.

It's not exactly what I was trying to do in the original project, since I basically bypassed the actual collection indices with my own system, but it does do the job as far as the user is concerned.

```
public class ViewTest : BindableBase
{
    public long SortOrder { get; set; }
}


private ObservableCollection<ViewTest> testViewList = new ObservableCollection<ViewTest>();

public ObservableCollection<ViewTest> TestViewList
{
    get { return this.testViewList; }
    private set { this.SetProperty<ObservableCollection<ViewTest>>(ref this.testViewList, value); }
}


<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TestViewList, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Order" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=SortOrder}" />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>


private void AddTest(string test)
{
    ViewTest newTest = new ViewTest();

    newTest.SortOrder = this.GetHighestSortOrder(this.TestViewList) + 1;

    this.TestViewList.Add(newTest);
}


private int GetHighestSortOrder(ObservableCollection<ViewTest> testList)
{
    int highest = 0;

    foreach (ViewTest test in testList)
    {
        if (test.SortOrder > highest)
        {
            highest = Convert.ToInt32(test.SortOrder);
        }
    }

    return highest;
}


private ObservableCollection<ViewTest> SortTests(ObservableCollection<ViewTest> testList)
{
    ObservableCollection<ViewTest> sortedList = new ObservableCollection<ViewTest>();

    while (testList.Count > 0)
    {
        int index = 0;
        int lowest = 0;
        while (index < testList.Count)
        {
            if (testList[index].SortOrder < testList[lowest].SortOrder)
            {
                lowest = index;
            }

            index += 1;
        }

        sortedList.Add(testList[lowest]);
        testList.RemoveAt(lowest);
    }

    return sortedList;
}
```

The functions to move items up and down are just swapping two SortOrder values, then calling the SortOrder function to rearrange the indices.