# Default AutoNumbered Column in Listview

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I would be displaying N number of items in Listview.

I want a default autonumber column in the listview.

Example:

```
1 ABC
2 SDSD
3 sdfsd
```

Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might have to add a RowNumber Property to your ModelView (which means you have to do it manually).

So basically a for loop through the items

```C#
// where items is the List of Models
for(int i = 0; i < items.Count; i++)
{
    items[i].RowProperty = i;
}
```

Then in your XAML

```XAML
<DataTemplate>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding RowProperty}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

---

Interesting links on the topic:

See [How to display row numbers in a ListView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/660528/how-to-display-row-numbers-in-a-listview)