# Add an index to a list to show a ranking from 1 to max items in the list

Tags: c#, linq, xaml

I'm using MVVM Light. I have to bind a result list to my XAML pages. I fill a list up with items from an XML file. Those items have no id or index.

However, I want to add index numbers to the bound listbox.

```
public async Task<List<MyClass>> getItemsList()
{
    var temp = await _IDataService.GetItems();
    List<MyClass> tempItemsList = new List<MyClass>();

    tempItemsList = (from Item in temp
                          orderby Item.Name descending
                          select Item).ToList();

    return tempItemsList;
}
```

On the XAML page, I use this code:

```
 <ListBox Grid.Row="1"
                 ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsList}"
                 ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                 ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                 Margin="18,0,0,18">
```

And then I can read out the properties from that list like this:

```
 <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
```

But before that, I want to place an index, e.g:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemsList.Index}" />
```

Any idea how I can add such an index?

Comment: [check](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/660528/how-to-display-row-numbers-in-a-listview) possible duplicated.

Comment: @dbvega I use a ListBox...

Comment: @dbvega hey your answer looks good but i cannot use the wpfcalc becouse im making a windows phone app.

Comment: add WindowsPhone tag, I have an update for the answer.

Comment: the `wpfcalc` is the name of registered namespace, you can change it according to your code. Open this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747086(v=vs.110).aspx) for more information.

Comment: @dbvega ah indeed, ok but i still get errors on the lines <local:StudentList/> and <local:ListBoxItemIndexConverter x:Key="ListBoxItemIndexConverter1" />

Comment: @dbvega nvm i forgot to make the converter public, it works! Thank you very much! Is there a way to start from 1 instead of 0?

Comment: yes of course there are. Change `return listBox.ItemContainerGenerator.IndexFromContainer(item);` for `return listBox.ItemContainerGenerator.IndexFromContainer(item) + 1;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*** The example is using zero-based index.

Example data model:

```cs
public class StudentList
{
    public List<Student> Students { get; set; }

    public StudentList()
    {
        Students = new List<Student>
        {
            new Student {Name = "Student 1"},
            new Student {Name = "Student 2"},
            new Student {Name = "Student 3"}
        };
    }
}

public class Student
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The converter:

```cs
public class ListBoxItemIndexConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        var dependencyObject = value as DependencyObject;
        var item = FindFirstParentOfType<ListBoxItem>(dependencyObject);

        if (item == null)
            return null;

        var listBox = (ListBox) ItemsControl.ItemsControlFromItemContainer(item);
        if (listBox == null)
            return null;

        return listBox.ItemContainerGenerator.IndexFromContainer(item);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    private static T FindFirstParentOfType<T>(DependencyObject dependencyObject) 
        where T : DependencyObject
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (dependencyObject == null)
                return null;

            var parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(dependencyObject);

            var findFirstParentOfType = (parent as T);

            if (findFirstParentOfType != null)
                return findFirstParentOfType;

            dependencyObject = parent;
        }
    }
}
```

And the view.

```xml
<Page
x:Class="WinPhoneStack.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:WinPhoneStack"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
<Page.DataContext>
    <!--sample data context-->
    <local:StudentList/>
</Page.DataContext>

<Page.Resources>
    <local:ListBoxItemIndexConverter x:Key="ListBoxItemIndexConverter1" />
</Page.Resources>

<Grid>
    <ListBox 
        ItemsSource="{Binding Students,Mode=OneTime}"
        ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
        ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
        Margin="18,0,0,18">

        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Converter={StaticResource ListBoxItemIndexConverter1}, Mode=OneTime}" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name,Mode=OneTime}" Margin="10 0"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: hmm this looks good but I can't add grid.datacontext and grid.resources

Comment: Are you sure i can use that in windows phone xaml?

Comment: @MujangiBia I did an update, now it support Windows Phone 8.1. Please, update the question tags, add windowsphone. If it helps, please, up/vote and mark as answer.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can implement the required functionality by returning instead of a List of 'MyClass' objects a list of custom objects that hold an index value and the required data from the original object (in the following example for simplicity I am returning a list of `Tuple<int, string>` objects):

```
public async Task<List<Tuple<int, string>>> getItemsList()
{
    var temp = await _IDataService.GetItems();
    List<MyClass> tempItemsList = new List<MyClass>();

    tempItemsList = (from Item in temp
                          orderby Item.Name descending
                          select Item).ToList();

    List<Tuple<int, string>> items = tempItemsList.Select((item, index) => new Tuple<int, string>(index + 1, item.Name));

    return items;
}
```

And then you can bind the values to the corresponding TextBlocks:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Item1}" /> // Index
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Item2}" /> // Name
```