# Show 1-D Array with index in WPF grid

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, wpf, datagrid

I have a 1 dimensional array of double values.

Using WPF, what is the best way to show the values in a grid with two columns for the array index (first column) and array value (second column)?

The first column is read only, but the second column should be editable.

In fact the data represent a time based sequence of values, at a fixed frequency, for example 20kHz. I can calculate the time for each sample as (start_time + index/frequency).

What would be the best way to show the data with three columns for the index, time and data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first solution was pretty good for showing read only data.

Editing an array of double values is - based on my current understanding - not possible. To edit a value it has to be defined as a property with setter and getter methods.

I didn't really want to do this, because it means creating a separate object for each element in the array. However, if I do this, the rest is easy and I can do without the value converters used in the first solution.

I have defined a class for each item in the grid:

```
public class DataItem
{
  int         _index ;
  double      _sampleTime ;
  ViewModel   _vm ;

  public DataItem ( int Index, double SampleTime, ViewModel vm )
  {
    _index      = Index ;
    _sampleTime = SampleTime ;
    _vm         = vm ;
  }

  public int Index
  {
    get { return _index ; }
  }

  public double SampleTime
  {
    get { return _sampleTime ; }
  }

  public double Value
  {
    get { return _vm.MyData[_index] ; }
    set { _vm.MyData[_index] = value ; }
  }
}
```

I create the objects in the view model in a simple loop. For simplicity I pass in the index and time as parameters. I pass in a reference to the ViewModel so that the setter for the array value can store the edited value back into the original array.

```
  _items = new List<DataItem>() ;
  for ( int i = 0 ; i < darray.Length ; i++ )
  {
    _items.Add ( new DataItem ( i, startTime + samplingRate * i, this ) ) ;
  }
```

I put this code in the constructor of the ViewModel, which is good enough for me. The ViewModel has an Items property which returns the collection.

In XAML I have used a DataGrid, because it supports editing directly.

```
<DataGrid x:Name="ValuesGrid"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" 
          AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
          CanUserReorderColumns="False" 
          CanUserResizeRows="False" 
          CanUserAddRows="False"
          HorizontalGridLinesBrush="DarkGray"
          VerticalGridLinesBrush="DarkGray"
          >

  <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Index" Binding="{Binding Index}"       Width="10*" IsReadOnly="True"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Time"  Binding="{Binding SampleTime}"  Width="20*" IsReadOnly="True"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Value" Binding="{Binding Value}"       Width="20*" IsReadOnly="False"/>
  </DataGrid.Columns>

</DataGrid>
```

Finally I want to repeat. The answer to the question is "you can't do it". Two-way binding to an array of double is not possible. You must wrap each item in a object with setter and getter methods for the value.

Answer (score 0):

I found the basic idea [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/660528/how-to-display-row-numbers-in-a-listview)

I have defined two converters, one for the index

```
public class IndexConverter : IValueConverter
{
  public object Convert(object value, Type TargetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
  {
      ListViewItem item = (ListViewItem) value;
      ListView listView = ItemsControl.ItemsControlFromItemContainer(item) as ListView;
      int index = listView.ItemContainerGenerator.IndexFromContainer(item);
      return index.ToString();
  }

  public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
  {
      throw new NotImplementedException();
  }
}
```

and one for the time

```
public class SampleTimeConverter : IValueConverter
{
  private double StartTime    = 0.0 ;
  private double SamplingRate = 20000.0 ;

  public object Convert(object value, Type TargetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
  {
    ListViewItem item = (ListViewItem) value;
    ListView listView = ItemsControl.ItemsControlFromItemContainer(item) as ListView;
    int    index = listView.ItemContainerGenerator.IndexFromContainer(item);
    double sampleTime = StartTime + index / SamplingRate ;
    return String.Format ( "{0:F5}", sampleTime ) ;
  }

  public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
  {
      throw new NotImplementedException();
  }
}
```

Later I will pass the StartTime and SamplingRate in as properties.

For this test I defined a ViewModel with a property `public double[] MyData`.

In XAML, I defined a ListView as follows:

```
<Window.Resources>
  <local:IndexConverter      x:Key="IndexConverter"/>
  <local:SampleTimeConverter x:Key="SampleTimeConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>

  <ListView Name="listviewNames" ItemsSource="{Binding MyData}">
    <ListView.View>
      <GridView>
        <GridView.Columns>

          <GridViewColumn Header="Index" Width="100"
            DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
                                           AncestorType={x:Type ListViewItem}}, 
                                           Converter={StaticResource IndexConverter}}" />

          <GridViewColumn Header="Time" Width="200"
            DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
                                           AncestorType={x:Type ListViewItem}}, 
                                           Converter={StaticResource SampleTimeConverter}}" />

          <GridViewColumn Header="Value" Width="auto" >
            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Mode=OneWay}" Width="200" BorderThickness="0"/>
              </DataTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
          </GridViewColumn>

        </GridView.Columns>
      </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
  </ListView>

</Grid>
```

This is more or less doing what I wanted.

I haven't yet tested whether the edited values are written back to the array. In fact I am pretty sure that Binding Mode=OneWay is wrong, but I think I will find a solution to that.

My only doubt is whether it might cause a performance problem to create a text box for each value (there may be thousands).